# How to mutably borrow reference from &&mut Foo?

Tags: rust

```
struct A;
impl A {
    fn foo(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A;
    let x = &{ &mut a };
    x.foo();
}
```

```
error[E0389]: cannot borrow data mutably in a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     x.foo();
  |     ^ assignment into an immutable reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You have an immutable reference, which means that *everything* behind the reference is immutable from the point of view of the owner of the reference.

If this wasn't the case, then the whole concept of there only being a single mutable reference to each thing at a time would be trivially breakable.